# How to run code on server on the click of button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a simple Next.js app with **dummy.js** file as follows:

```
class Dummy extends React.Component{

    static async getInitialProps(ctx){
        return { dummy : 'abc'};
    }

    displayHelloWorld(params) {
      console.log(params.dummy);
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.displayHelloWorld(this.props)}>Click Me!</button>
    }
}

export default Dummy;
```

I run the app using the command `npm run dev` and go to `localhost:3000/dummy`. I was expecting `displayHelloWorld` function to run only when I click on *Click Me!* button but it is invoked on page load itself.

My goal is to invoke and run function on the server side(on click of button). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `<button onClick={this.foo(args)}>...</button>` actually trigger the function once upon rendering the component.

A simple solution will be to pass a function callback, such as `onClick={()=>this.foo(args)}`.

This will make sure the function will be called every time upon pressing the button.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are invoking the `this.displayHelloWorld()` method directly in the render function. You can wrap it inside an arrow function:

```
return <button onClick={() => this.displayHelloWorld(this.props)}>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it is running only when I click on the button but it is running on the client side(console statements are appearing in browser console but not in terminal where I am running the command `npm run dev`). How/what change is needed to run the function on the server side?

Comment: By default React.js uses client-side rendering, when you press the button -> the JS runs on the client and trigger the function.
If you wish to run it on the server - you got 2 options really: 1) Use a server-side rendering platform; or 2) Activate a trigger that effect the server-side, such as fetching an API.
The current behavior is totally normal, I would advice to leave it that way, And if you're interested - check this to learn about React SSR (Server Side Rendering): https://youtu.be/NwyQONeqRXA